# ¿Cómo actualizar una columna de una tabla desde otra comparando varios campos?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Tengo dos tablas una llamada direcTel y la otra emp.

La primer tabla "direcTel" tiene el campo, nombre y otro campo que es emp.

La segunda tabla "emp" tiene el campo, nombre, apepat, apemat, emp.

Lo que quiero realizar es que los datos que están en el campo emp de la tabla emp se pasen a la tabla direcTel en el campo emp.

Lo que tengo hasta ahora es la siguiente consulta:

```
UPDATE Per
SET 
Per.emp=Addr.emp
FROM direcTel Per
INNER JOIN
emp Addr
ON Per.nombre = Addr.nombre
WHERE Per.nombre in ( SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(primero.nombre)) +' '+ LTRIM(RTRIM(primero.apepat))+' '+LTRIM(RTRIM(primero.apemat)) AS nombre
FROM emp primero
INNER JOIN direcTel segundo on LTRIM(RTRIM(primero.nombre)) +' '+ LTRIM(RTRIM(primero.apepat))+' '+LTRIM(RTRIM(primero.apemat)) = segundo.nombre
WHERE primero.nombre != ''
 )
```

Estoy tratando de enlazar por nombre completo, ejemplo:

En mi tabla direcTel tengo en el primer dato en el campo Nombre: Jose Juan Ortiz Sanches

En mi tabla Emp los tengo por separado, nombre, apepat, apemat.

Entonces no se como juntar esto, para que me enlace con todo el nombre completo.
¿Alguna idea? saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, espero esto te ayude, y te dejo unos comentarios:

```
UPDATE Per
SET 
Per.emp=Addr.emp
FROM direcTel Per
INNER JOIN
emp Addr
ON per.nombre=(LTRIM(RTRIM(Addr.nombre)) +' '+ LTRIM(RTRIM(Addr.apepat))+' '+LTRIM(RTRIM(Addr.apemat)))
```

Lo ideal sería que tuvieras una llave foránea que uniera tus empleados con la tabla "directel".
Otro punto es que si hay empleados con el mismo nombre te asignará el mismo resultado a ambos.
Espero te sirva.